# How practical is it to use ./ in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to linux, so far I can navigate through directories easily and change file permissions, I can also do some python/java stuff within the terminal. My question is that when I am using cd/ls/rm and such, I always use ./ when I am referencing subdirectories. Is this a good or bad habit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./file_name` is used to exec a file which is into the current directory. Obviously this file must be executable.

If you want to change into a sub-directory just type

```
cd sub-directory_name
```

Which is the same that

```
cd ./sub-directory_name
```

Comment: I thought ./ was just to specify the directory you are currently in? like in my home folder I'll do cd ./workspace instead of cd workspace

Comment: Exact! So it is a good habit, I guess. But this ./ is more useful when you wish exec a file, e.g. a bash script

Comment: Welcome to GNU/Linux world! :-

Comment: using `./file_name` is for security purposes.  Linux by default does NOT add `.` to the `$PATH` so you can't just untarball a package and the person be sneaky and have a nasty binary named `ls` that you just executed.  This forces you to type `./ls` if you really do intend on executing this new binary in your current directory (`.`) instead of the typical `ls`.

Comment: Yeah @UtahJarhead!, I agree with you.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I was just expounding on what you'd already put up.  Didn't want to steal your thunder or your answer vote.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using `$CDPATH`, there is one more distinction between `cd subdir` and `cd ./subdir`: the first one searches CDPATH if the directory is not found in the current directory, while the second does not; moreover, the first one ouputs the target path to standard output, while the second does not.